# Response as mail attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, httpresponse

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                compositeLink.PrintingSystem.ExportToPdf(stream);
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = false;
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf");
                Response.BinaryWrite(stream.GetBuffer());
                Response.End();


            }
```

I got this working fine. Next step is to send this pdf file to mail, as attachment

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                compositeLink.PrintingSystem.ExportToPdf(stream);
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = false;
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf");
                Response.BinaryWrite(stream.GetBuffer());




                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                message.To.Add("someone@example.net");
                message.Subject = "Subject";
                message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("someoneelse@example.net");
                message.Body = "Body";
                message.Attachments.Add(Response.BinaryWrite(stream.GetBuffer()));
                System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("192.168.100.100");
                smtp.Send(message);

                Response.End();

        }
```

I have problem with this line:

```
message.Attachments.Add(Response.BinaryWrite(stream.GetBuffer()));
```

Any help how to get this to work? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Response.BinaryWrite is going to take the contents of the stream and write them to the response.  You don't want that.

Instead, you have to create a new [Attachment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx) object and add that to message.Attachments.

Try this:

```
var ct = new ContentType();
ct.MediaType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf;
ct.Name = "test.pdf";
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, ct));
```

You can find more example code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sdktyws.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this;

```
message.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(stream, "test.pdf", "application/pdf"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Response.BinaryWrite` method returns `void` which means that you are passing nothing into the `Add` method.

What you should consider doing is using your stream directly to create an `Attachment` instance, adding that to the message's collection.  That would look something like:

```
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "file.pdf"));
```

A full example of sending mail with an attachment can be found on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments.aspx).  Hope that helps.